# scikit-plot scaling is wrong

Tags: jupyter-notebook, scikit-plot

I'm trying to plot a confusion matrix in a jupyter notebook and the plot does not display properly.

My code is:

```
import scikitplot
plt.close()

scikitplot.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predicted_test)
```

and this code produces the plot:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to get the plot to display properly will be greatly appreciated.

Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have matplotlib==3.1.1 version installed, just downgrade it.
I have encountered the same problem and version == "3.0.3" works fine.

The problem is with the "imshow" function because the same issue araises when plotting heatmap from the seaborn package.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import scikitplot


scikitplot.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predicted_test)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your suggestion did not help.  I get the same display.